# Multiplication between booleans in linear programming (python, Pulp library)

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I'm looking for a solution to a linear programming problem and I need to define the following constraints:

```
gji = 1 if guest j is seated at table i, 0 otherwise 
gki = 1 if guest k is seated at table i, 0 otherwise  
pjik = gij * gik = 1 if guest j AND guest k are seated at table i, 0 otherwise
```

I wrote the first two costrains (using the Pulp library), but I don't know how to represent the multiplication of `gji*gki`

My code:

```
Gji = LpVariable.matrix("Gji",(range(0,number_guest),range(0,number_table)),lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat='binary')

Gki = LpVariable.matrix("Gki",(range(0,number_guest),range(0,number_table)),lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat='binary')

for row in range (0,number_guest):
    prob += lpSum(Gji[row])<=1
    prob += lpSum(Gji[row])>=1

for columns in range (0,number_table):
    prob += lpSum(np.matrix(Gji).T[columns].tolist()) <= a
```

How can I write the costrain for `Pjki`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always first formulate a proper mathematical model, before implementing it in PuLp.

Let

```
g(i,k) = 1 if guest i sits at table k
         0 otherwise
```

and

```
p(i,j,k) = 1 if guests i and j sit at table k
           0 otherwise
```

First you need some assignment constraints:

```
sum(i, g(i,k)) <= capacity(k)  for all k
sum(k, g(i,k)) = 1             for all i
```

The binary multiplication

```
p(i,j,k) = g(i,k) * g(j,k)
```

can be linearized as

```
p(i,j,k) <= g(i,k)
p(i,j,k) <= g(j,k)
p(i,j,k) >= g(i,k)+g(j,k)-1
p(i,j,k) ∈ {0,1}
```

Usually we don't need all of these variables and equations, but that depends on the details of the model. For sure we should only consider `i<j`. Interestingly, this formulation is so tight, we can relax p(i,j,k) to be continuous between 0 and 1: they will be integer automatically.

This mathematical description is easily transcribed into Python/Pulp. You probably should redo your Python code as it has some nonsensical things. Some hints:

- binary variables already have bounds 0 and 1
- Pulp can do equality constraints (writing <= and >= constraints is silly)
- try to make things more readable (closer to the mathematical representation)
- for a different approach see [wedding.py](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/blob/master/examples/wedding.py)